# Codeigniter: Controller cannot load view

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to load a view from a controller but i am not able to do so? I am not getting any error but the view doesn't appear. In the search input field of my page i use ajax to get suggestions from the db for the typed in text:

```
function get_users($hint)
{
    if($hint!="")
    {
        $this->db->select('email,first_name');
        $this->db->like('email',$hint,'after');
        $query=$this->db->get('users');
        $row=$query->result_array();
        $name=$row[0]['first_name'];
        echo "<a href=/codeigniter/index.php/user_view/view_profile/$name >".$name."</a><br>";       
    }
    else
    {
        echo "";
    }
}
```

This sends the name of user as a link to the view. When i click the link it calls a controller which then loads the profile of the user (say whose name is contained in $name).

the code of that controller is

```
function view_profile($name)
{
    $data['user']=$name;
    $this->load->view('profile',$data);
}
```

A new page opens but the profile doesn't load. It's just a blank page. Can anybody help?

Comment: can you show `/views/profile.php` file?

Comment: Do really want to have a look its around 350 lines. And its loading perfectly fine when i called it after log in using a different controller.It's just that this call just can't load it

Comment: @Girish thanks for the response i got the solution

Comment: pls be specify about your question and provides all you code what u try

Answer (score 0):

Why not redirect to user_view/view_profile right from get_users function? 
I mean instead of **echo "".$name."
";**
     you may try to write **redirect('user_view/view_profile/'.$name);**
And one more thing in config/config.php enable logs (If you haven't enabled them yet) , log files are so usefull in troubleshooting.

Comment: But i want the suggestions to be available in the view for the user to see.If then the user clicks on the name of a particular person it takes him to the profile of the desired user.Thanks for the useful tip.I will enable logs right away.